# Sort array of objects by date in dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss format

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, sorting, object

I have a large array of objects with a string type date field with format dd/mm/yyyyy HH:mm:ss and I can't reorder it properly.

The array looks like this

```
cases[
   {
      name: a, 
      date:03/04/2020 17:24:17
   },
   {
      name: b, 
      date:04/05/2020 07:21:19
   },
   {
      name: c, 
      date:02/01/2020 11:35:50
   },
]
```

And I tried to reorder it in the following way but without results

```
cases.sort(function(a,b){
                   var dateA=new Date(a.date), dateB=new Date(b.date)
                   return dateA - dateB
        });
```

Comment: What insights did you find during debugging?

Comment: `new Date()` won't work with `dd/MM` format. Search for how to parse dates with dd/MM to date object in javascript. You can use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) or build a simple parser like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38593735/3082296

Comment: If you do yyyy/mm/dd you do not need a function to sort

Comment: returns me the dates as if the format was mm/dd/yyyy I think, without even considering the time

Comment: @mplungjan i need this format i can't convert it in another one

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
cases = [{
  name: "a",
  date: "03/04/2020 17:24:17"
}, {
  name: "b",
  date: "04/05/2020 07:21:19"
}, {
  name: "c",
  date: "02/01/2020 11:35:50"
}, ]

const makeDate = str => {
  const [_, dd, mm, yyyy, hh, min, ss] = str.match(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
  return new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd, hh, min, ss)
};

cases.sort((a, b) => makeDate(a.date) - makeDate(b.date))

console.log(cases)
```